# Element type "style" must be followed by either attribute specifications, ">" or "/>

Tags: javascript, css, xml, styles

### Element type "style"

#### ```
Element type "style" must be followed by either attribute specifications, ">" or "/>"
```

when i save xml code ( template blogger ) getting some error. please help me

```
I have this code
```

```
Prism.languages.css['atrule'].inside.rest = Prism.util.clone(Prism.languages.css);
    if (Prism.languages.markup) {
        Prism.languages.insertBefore('markup', 'tag', {
            'style': {
                pattern: /(<style[\w\W]*?>)[\w\W]*?(?=<\/style>)/i,
                lookbehind: true,
                inside: Prism.languages.css,
                alias: 'language-css'
            }
        });
```

getting error : in [pattern](/questions/tagged/pattern) after style

```
pattern: /(<style[\w\W]*?>)[\w\W]*?(?=<\/style>)/i,
```

i've trying the start of tag `<` to `&lt;` still error

[css](/questions/tagged/css)

#### thanks before

Comment: What are you trying to determine or match? Is inquiry relating to `style` attribute, or `<style>` element? `style` attribute does not have closing `>` or `/>` characters.

Comment: isn't `[\w\W]` same as `.` because `\W` is "not" `\w` so `[\w\W]` is any character at all